# Is it possible to Shell a Java GUI application from a VB6 application?

Tags: java, swing, shell, vb6, 64-bit

I have a fancy new Java Swing application that I have wrapped in a .EXE using Launch4J (for the icon and no other reason). I've now been instructed to add functionality to this incredibly old VB6 legacy application that, on clicking a button, will launch the new Java application. The only reason I can think of that this is not working is that the JRE with which I am working is 64 bit and the vb6 application with which I am working is obviously not, and that they aren't playing nice or something.

My understanding was that it should be as simple as:

```
Shell """" & PATH_TO_FILE & """"
```

but that's not working.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Shell """" & App.path & "\JR3GUI.exe""" 'Path to exe directly.'
Shell "javaw -jar """ & App.path & "\JR3GUI.jar""" 'Try to execute the .jar directly'
Shell """" & App.path & "\JR3GUI.bat""" 'Batch file with the following:'

    @ECHO OFF
    start javaw -jar JR3GUI.jar
    javaw -jar JR3GUI.jar
    start JR3GUI.exe
    JR3GUI.exe

ShellExecute 0, """" & App.Path & "\JR3GUI.exe""", "", "", 1 'ShellExecute the .exe'
ShellExecute 0, "javaw", "-jar """ & App.Path & "\JR3GUI.jar""", "", 1 'ShellExecute to run the .jar directly'
ShellExecute 0, """" & App.Path & "\JR3GUI.bat""", "", "", 1 'ShellExecute the batch file.'
```

none of these worked, and I don't know why.

For `ShellExecute` I'm working with a pre-existing implementation of the API, but I'm sure it works because it worked for what they were using before.
I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, the VB6 application was compiled in a virtual XP environment.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does it work with `java -jar ...` if you provide the full path to the java.exe binary?

Comment: No. I get an error message about something null.

Comment: It's an EXE, you should be running the EXE. And yes, you need to use 32-bit if the VB6 app is 32-bit.

Comment: Considered sharing the error message?  It might actually contain information relevant to solving the problem...

Comment: When shelling to a program bitness is irelevent. So `shell "c:\somefolder\mycompiledjar.exe"`. If your path has spaces `shell chr(34) & "c:\somefolder\mycompiledjar.exe" & chr(34)`

Comment: PS: Try typing `iexpress` to get a setup program that can be used to wrap scripts. It doesn't do icons but you can use ResHacker (http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker) to change the icon.

Comment: I would like to know, if executing any program (so not java in particular but for example calc.exe) works on the virtual machine and Win7. So that we have a reference, if the main idea works.

Comment: @quant:
The original application had no problem launching the application that was being replaced. The way it was before was that the program would be able to launch another .exe, and it had no problem with it (the other .exe was done in vb6 too)

Answer (score 0):

We were finally able to resolve the problem. I don't know exactly what the issue was but we had to create a batch file that killed the application and then ran the .exe pointing to the .jar file.

So it ended up like this:

```
Shell """" & App.path & "\JR3GUI.bat"""
```

and in the .bat

```
taskkill /f /im "FILENAME.exe"
start JR3GUI.exe
```

That worked, and it was the only thing that did.